# Excel VBA Outlook automation code segment works in one workbook, but not in another one

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to transfer one piece of code to another workbook. The code works perfectly on workbook1 but generates a

> compile error User-defined type not defined

When run on workbook2.

Here is the code in question.

```
' Set up Outlook Namespace
Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim olNS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olFol As Outlook.Folder

Set olNS = OL.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFol = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

' Current users address
Address = olNS.Accounts.Item(1).SmtpAddress
```

The error comes from `olNS As Outlook.Namespace`

Comment: What `Workbook` ??? the code you have is related to **Outlook** !

Comment: Check the references included in the first workbook versus the second.

Comment: @ShaiRado - could be [tag:excel-vba] but mix and matching early and late binding

Comment: Thank you @RobinMackenzie that is the answer. I feel so silly overlooking it. If you put this in a response I will flag it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is generated because although you use late binding for `OL` you are still using early binding for `olNS` and have likely not set the reference for Outlook in the second workbook.

If you want to use late binding then do this, e.g.:

```
Dim olNS As Object
Set olNS = CreateObject("Outlook.Namespace")

Dim olFol As Object
Set olFol = CreateObject("Outlook.Folder")

'etc...
```

Or just set a reference to Outlook in the second workbook:

[image]

Comment: No worries - happy coding :)